# robot framework equivalent of "from dir1.dir2 import file " in python

Tags: python, import, robotframework, libraries

*Hi
I am new to robot frame work so in my local library's I have a file which is encapsulated in two directories , i want to access some functions form that file so how can I import that as a library in my robot test suit*

**libraries/dir1/dir2/file.py** -- is the file path (in python files)>

tried to add it as library with >
"""dir1.dir2.file """ --but it throws an error >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following on top of your code

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation      My Robot Tests

Library     folder1/folder2/file.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Examble:

```
Library           ../../folder/file.py
```

Comment: Could you elaborate this answer?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck